# Batch file to copy certain directories and contents from one location to another location with date and time?

Tags: windows, batch

I am trying to back up certain folders every hour or so to another drive and have a bat file create a new folder with date and time along with a prefix?
How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
md "Z:\destinationfolder\prefix_%DATE:~6,4%_%DATE:~3,2%_%DATE:~0,2%_postfix"
xcopy /S /Y "X:\sourcefolder\*.*" "Z:\destinationfolder\prefix_%DATE:~6,4%_%DATE:~3,2%_%DATE:~0,2%_postfix\"
```

where

- X: - source folders drive
- sourcefolder - folder which contains subfolers to be copied (maybe root)
- prefix,postfix - static destination backup folder name partsparts
- *.* - mask for folders/files names which must be copied
- Z: - destination drive
- destinationfolder - folder where backup folder must be created